# Background Image Isn't Moving

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm having trouble adjusting an image (folk.jpg) so that it covers the background of my page, just underneath the navigation bar. I've tried adjusting the size, but it doesn't seem to want to do anything. I'm wondering if there's something in my CSS that's preventing me from adjusting the image. Here's the code:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.topnav .search-container button {
  float: right;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  background: #ddd;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.topnav a {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav .search-container {
  float: right;
}

.topnav input[type=text] {
  padding: 6px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #D7D2D2;
}

.topnav .search-container button {
  background: #5AA797;
  margin-top: 6px;
  color: white;
}

.banner {
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="topnav">
  <div class="search-container">
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <input type="text" placeholder="search" name="search">
      <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <a class="active" href="#about">ABOUT</a>
  <a href="#news">NEWS</a>
  <a href="#events">EVENTS</a>
  <a href="#contact">CONTACT</a>
</div>

<div class="banner">
  <img class="imgheader" src="/Users/Desktop/folk.jpg" alt="folk band">
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see a [background image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image). Can you help to clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you're probably going to want to have actual *content* underneath your header, rather than just the image, I'd recommend making use of the **[`background-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image)** CSS property rather than an `<img>` tag. This will make it so that content entered into `.banner` (or similar) will be able to sit on *top* of the background.

For this, you're looking for `background-image: url('')`. That, in combination with **[`background-size: cover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)** (which you already have on `.banner`), will give you the background image, but it will only take up a sliver of the height. As such, you'll need to specify the **[`height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height)**, taking the navbar into consideration.

This can be done with the **[`calc()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)**, subtracting the height of the navbar from `100%`. In my snippet, this is `96px`, though note that you don't actually specify a fixed height for the navbar. As such, you may want to make use of **[`media queries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)** to adjust this 'offset' at different resolutions.

Finally, you'll want to remove the **[`margin-top: -10px`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-top)** from `.banner` so that it sits 'flush' up against your navbar.

All of this can be seen in the following:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.topnav .search-container button {
  float: right;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  background: #ddd;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.topnav a {
  float: right;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav .search-container {
  float: right;
}

.topnav input[type=text] {
  padding: 6px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  background-color: #D7D2D2;
}

.topnav .search-container button {
  background: #5AA797;
  margin-top: 6px;
  color: white;
}

.banner {
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/100');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: calc(100% - 96px);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .banner {
    height: calc(100% - 48px);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="indyfolk.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src=""></script>
  <title>Indy Folk News</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="topnav">
    <div class="search-container">
      <form action="/action_page.php">
        <input type="text" placeholder="search" name="search">
        <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <a class="active" href="#about">ABOUT</a>
    <a href="#news">NEWS</a>
    <a href="#events">EVENTS</a>
    <a href="#contact">CONTACT</a>
  </div>
  <div class="banner">
  </div>
  
</body>

</html>
```

Also, as an aside, you have an erroneous `</script>` tag at the end of your Font Awesome reference :)

Comment: This worked perfectly. I'll look into setting a fixed height for the navbar. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In your way, the image will display on the div you defined (`banner`). If you want to make it a background image, you just set your css:

```
html { 
  background: url(ImagePath) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```